# DAX - CONCATENATEX TO FILTER AN UNRELATED TABLE

Tags: dax

I have an unrelated table ('Selected Values Slicer') that is then used as a slicer to select values. I need to use these selected values to filter another table ('Results Table').

Doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect it to. The output shows a 0 when more then 1 item is selected but works ok when 1 value is selected

**VAR __SelectedValues** =

CONCATENATEX(
ALLSELECTED('Selected Values Slicer'[Description]),
'Selected Values Slicer'[Description],
",")

**RETURN**

**CALCULATE(**
[TotalCount],
'Results Table'[Description] IN {__SelectedValues}
)

---

**__SelectedValues** RETURNS "Selected Value 1,Selected Value 2"

What I'm expecting is **__SelectedValues** to RETURN "Selected Value 1","Selected Value 2"

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax will return "Selected Value 1","Selected Value 2" as you asks

```
CONCATENATEX(
    ALLSELECTED('Selected Values Slicer'[Description])
    ,"""" & 'Selected Values Slicer'[Description] & """"
    ,","
)
```

Regarding filtering. I was trying to use the string as filter, but I didn't manage it the way you want. I can't say what is the reason for DAX not to do that, but asked Marco Russo about the case. So, I'll add the answer since a get it (upd. the answer added to the end of the answer).

To filter the table with a string of `CONCATENAX()` you can try  the following sytax ( I checked it with a dummy data):

```
VAR __SelectedValues =
        CONCATENATEX(
            ALLSELECTED('Selected Values Slicer'[Description])
            ,'Selected Values Slicer'[Description]
            ,","
        )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        [TotalCount]
        ,FILTER(
               'Results Table'
               ,CONTAINSSTRING(
                    __SelectedValues
                   ,'Results Table'[Description]
               )
        )
    )
```

Regarding result you want to achieve. A below code, I believe, is enough. You have a slicer and you want to apply its values to the result. I have a feeling, you don't need to change a contex to the slicer and no context can influence it. If it's not like that, then the code should be altered, but the idea remains the same - get a column with a unique values and use it as a filter. I checked the syntax and it was functioning.

```
CALCULATE(
    [TotalCount]
    ,'Results Table'[Description] IN VALUES('Selected Values Slicer'[Description]) 
)
```

P.S.
My first answer was not ok. I messed some info and gave an incorrect input. I'm sorry for that.

P.S.S. The answer from Marco Russo:

"IN looks for an exact match in a table (IN VALUE is a better choice for your need, and a better one is:

TREATAS ( VALUES ( slicer[column1] ), table[color] )

The result of CONCATENATEX is a string, so you should use CONTAINSSTRING - DAX Guide to do the search, but it would be slower and potentially inaccurate."

This is the answer from his colleague

[image]

Comment: will it work like CONCATENATEX(
    VALUES('Selected Values Slicer'[Description])
    ,[Description]
    ,","
)

Comment: @UmutK nice to have reply from you! This, I think, gru needs. Do you think it not fits him?

Comment: hi again, i was trying to make it shorter if it works =) i would prefer to make a relationship instead of way-arounds =)

Comment: that doesn't work...

the result set still returns a string just like in my example

the filter is expecting something like this :-
   "Selected Value 1","Selected Value 2"
However, the code is returning the same but without the "" like this
   "Selected Value 1,Selected Value 2"

Comment: @UmutK I was wrong with the answer and gave a new one, so you can check it. BR.

Comment: @UmutK, I managed to filter the table with a concatanated string  )

Comment: @Mik Well done! but I junt dont understand why gru needs to concatenate the same value twice ? ))) It would be perfect sense with some sample data or sample file.